# Using colorbox as a mega modal menu

Tags: colorbox

For a client, I need to design a modal menu if you will... a menu bar with two items, clicking on either one of them opens a modal window with more links and a close button. I figured I would tweak the colorbox around, use the inline HTML option and give it a fixed positioning right below the navigation to achieve the desired result. However, I do have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a way to force the user to close the colorbox by clicking the close button rather than by clicking anywhere on the page?
2. When one clicks one of the links thereby opening the modal window, it dims the rest of the page, however I do need the active menu to look 'enabled', the easiest way I've found to achieve this is to add an identical div within the hidden div element and to position it right on top of the original link but just give it a brighter background color. Is duplicating the original navigational item an unnecessarily complicated way of doing things (sorry if that last bit isn't super clear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answers are Yes and Yes (I Think).  For #1, you need to set the **OverLayClose** parameter to false; for #2, the best way to change the appearance of the pulgin is to revise its CSS style sheet.  You should consider editing the rule for **#cboxOverlay** instead of adding more stuff.

This is all in the plugin's doc-o at http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

So go for it.